# Get text of a text box that was created at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

In my app, I create a text box at the runtime, here is the code

```
TextBox bt = new TextBox();
bt.Name = "population_textbox";
bt.Height = 20;
bt.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
bt.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
temp_grid.Children.Add(bt);
```

So, how to get the Text of this text box after user type something and enter. I don't know how to do it, I try

```
var tb = (FrameworkElement)this.FindName("population_textbox") as TextBox;
Console.Write(tb.Text);
```

And this is the error alert:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Comment: Console.Write(((FrameworkElement)this.FindName("population_textbox") as TextBox).Text.ToString());

Comment: Does `temp_grid` have a method called `FindName(..)`? if it does, try calling it instead of `this.FindName(..)`

Comment: @zey: the same result, exception has been thrown

Comment: What is `this` (Type) in your context?

Comment: @Jens Kloster: no, the temp_grid is only the local variable, so outer scope can't see it!

Comment: @Jehof: this is Window instance public partial class MainWindow : Window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should declare your control and then call RegisterName method that makes the control accessible, then you can refer to the control name from anywhere in your window scope:

```
        TextBox bt = new TextBox();
        bt.Name = "population_textbox";
        bt.Height = 20;
        bt.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
        bt.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
        temp_grid.Children.Add(bt);
        this.RegisterName(bt.Name, bt);


        var tb = this.FindName("population_textbox") as TextBox;
        Console.Write(tb.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

I write an simple example for you:

```
 TextBox bt = new TextBox();
            bt.Name = "population_textbox";
            bt.Text = "some";
            bt.Height = 20;
            main_Grid.Children.Add(bt);
            foreach (TextBox txt in main_Grid.Children)
            {
                if (txt is TextBox)
                {
                    if ((txt as TextBox).Name == "population_textbox")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show((txt as TextBox).Text);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use following code:**

```
 this.RegisterName("bt", textBox);
```

Also try:

```
var tb = (FrameworkElement)this.FindName("population_textbox");
```

**OR Directly write:**

```
TextBox bt = new TextBox();
bt.Name = "population_textbox";
bt.Height = 20;
bt.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
bt.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
temp_grid.Children.Add(bt);
Console.Write(bt.Text);
```

[without taking it in tb var].

This is used to get the text from textbox whose value is assigned runtime.

Comment: Can you give me a full tiny example? I am a newbie in C#

Comment: I receive this exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: do you mean i register a textbox name "bt" and then call directly bt.Text? of course it didn't work!

Comment: it definitely work, but not the answer I need, because the textbox declare is in another scope with the last use, and bt is a local variable, so, in another function can't access this

Comment: you can declare global variable for this and then assign its value directly so that it can get accessible to whole code.